# How to initialize array and fill with chars from buffer?

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following method:

```
int create_nodes(Source* source, int maxTokens) {
    int nodeCount = 0;
    Token* p_Tstart = source->tknBuffer;
    Token* p_Tcurrent = source->tknBuffer;

    while ((p_Tcurrent - p_Tstart) < maxTokens && p_Tcurrent != NULL) {
        int szWord = p_Tcurrent->t_L;
        char word[szWord];
        //  void *memset(void *str, int c, size_t n)
        memset(word, '\0', sizeof(char)*szWord);
        //  void *memcpy(void *str1, const void *str2, size_t n)
        char* p_T = source->buffer + p_Tcurrent->t_S;
        memcpy(word, p_T, szWord);

        if (word == ";") {
            ++p_Tcurrent;

            continue;
        }

        ++p_Tcurrent;
        ++nodeCount;
    }
}
```

`source` contains a `char*` buffer. The intent of the method is to first count all tokens in the buffer that are not a `;` token (and arrive at how many nodes we will need). Here is the buffer I am using: `11 + 31;`. The tokens - by this point - have been created as follows:

- `11`
- `+`
- `31`
- `;`

I pass in a `token*` which contains a start (`t_S`) and a length (`t_L`). So, for instance, the token representing the `+` char:

- `t->t_S` = 3
- `t->t_L` = 1

At `memcpy(...)`, the debugger jumps to `++p_Tcurrent` meaning that nothing was copied to `word` - essentially an uncaught exception I guess. What am I doing wrong to initialize the word array? And then to fill it with the specific information specified by the token?

`source.h`:

```
struct source {
    const char* fileName;
    char* buffer;
    int bufLen;
    Token* tknBuffer;
    Node* nodeBuffer;
    Expression* exprBuffer;
};
```

`token.h`:

```
struct token {
    int t_S;
    int t_L;
};
```

Comment: Please, add the Token and Source type declarations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not right.

```
if (word == ";") {
```

That will compare two pointers and will most likely be false all the time.

I suspect you meant to use:

```
// Test whether the first character is a semicolon
if (word[0] == ';') {
```

or

```
// Test whether the entire word is a semicolon
if (strcmp(word, ";") == 0) {
```

Comment: Strange enough, even though the debugger appeared to skip over this instruction, when I corrected it, I was able to get through the comparison.

Comment: Would `strcmp` depend on '\0' terminated *strings*?

Comment: Yes. Without that, you run the risk of accessing out of bounds memory.

Comment: @IAbstract: make your `szWord` one byte larger, and add the zero at the end where you now have `memcpy` to fix it.

Comment: `malloc(szWord + 1)` essentially, and `memset` with '\0'.